# R: selecting rows of data frame based on several criteria

Tags: r

I have created a data frame `my.df` and wish to select rows (or delete rows) based on several criteria.  With this example data frame I want to keep rows 1, 2, 4, 7 and 8.  Specifically, I want to:

1. keep any row containing a number in columns 3, 4 or 5
2. keep any row containing all missing observations in columns 3-5 if columns 1 and 2
   are not blank and do not contain junk

I can do this, but my solution seems overly complex and I am hoping someone may suggest a more efficient approach.

```
my.df <- data.frame(C1 = c("group1", "group1",     "",     "", "junk", "junk", "group2",       ""),
                    C2 = c(     "A",      "B",     "",     "",     "", "junk",      "B",      "C"),
                    C3 = c(     100,       NA,     NA,     10,     NA,     NA,       NA,       NA),
                    C4 = c(     200,       NA,     NA,     20,     NA,     NA,      100,       NA),
                    C5 = c(     100,       NA,     NA,     30,     NA,     NA,       NA,        5))

my.df

# the number of missing observations in columns 3-5 is < 3 or
# when the number of missing observations in columns 3-5 is 3 neither column 1 nor 2 is either blank or 'junk'

df.2 <- my.df[ (rowSums(is.na(my.df[,3:5]))  < (ncol(my.df)-2)) | 
               (rowSums(is.na(my.df[,3:5])) == (ncol(my.df)-2) & my.df[,1] != 'junk' & my.df[,2] != 'junk'  & my.df[,1] != '' & my.df[,2] != '') , ]
df.2
```

With my actual data what qualifies as junk can be complex.  So, here I generalize `junk` to `junk1` and `junk2` and I still want to keep rows 1, 2, 4, 7 and 8.  The code below works.

```
my.df <- data.frame(C1 = c("group1", "group1",     "",     "", "junk2", "junk1", "group2",       ""),
                    C2 = c(     "A",      "B",     "",     "",      "", "junk1",      "B",      "C"),
                    C3 = c(     100,       NA,     NA,     10,      NA,      NA,       NA,       NA),
                    C4 = c(     200,       NA,     NA,     20,      NA,      NA,      100,       NA),
                    C5 = c(     100,       NA,     NA,     30,      NA,      NA,       NA,        5))

my.df

df.3 <- my.df[ (rowSums(is.na(my.df[,3:5]))  < (ncol(my.df)-2)) | 
               (rowSums(is.na(my.df[,3:5])) == (ncol(my.df)-2)  & 
                my.df[,1] != 'junk1' & my.df[,2] != 'junk1'     & 
                my.df[,1] != 'junk2' & my.df[,2] != 'junk2'     &
                my.df[,1] != '' & my.df[,2] != '') 

        , ]
df.3
```

Because strings that qualify as junk become quite varied and complex here I try to simplify the code a little using %in% to group junk, but I obtain an error.

```
all.junk <- c("", "junk1", "junk2")

my.df.1 <- my.df[,1]
my.df.2 <- my.df[,2]

my.df.1 <- as.character(my.df.1)
my.df.2 <- as.character(my.df.2)

df.4 <- my.df[ (rowSums(is.na(my.df[,3:5]))  < (ncol(my.df)-2)) | 
               (rowSums(is.na(my.df[,3:5])) == (ncol(my.df)-2) & 
                my.df.1[!(my.df.1%in%all.junk)] & my.df.2[!(my.df.2%in%all.junk)]) , ]
df.4
```

I could proceed with the functional code I have, adding a new line to `df.3` for each character string that qualifies as junk, but I suspect there is a much more efficient solution.

I have found similar questions on Stackoverflow, but none that I have found seem to be dealing with as many or as complicated selection criteria as in this example.

Thank you for any suggestions, but particularly regarding the error in `df.4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty compact: keep every row that isn't all junk/nas:

```
all.junk=c("junk","")
subset(my.df,!(C1%in%all.junk &
               C2%in%all.junk & 
               is.na(C3) & is.na(C4) & is.na(C5)))
```

outputs

```
      C1 C2  C3  C4  C5
1 group1  A 100 200 100
2 group1  B  NA  NA  NA
4            10  20  30
7 group2  B  NA 100  NA
8         C  NA  NA   5
```

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is readability, you could refactor this code:

```
df.3 <- my.df[ (rowSums(is.na(my.df[,3:5]))  < (ncol(my.df)-2)) | 
           (rowSums(is.na(my.df[,3:5])) == (ncol(my.df)-2)  & 
            my.df[,1] != 'junk1' & my.df[,2] != 'junk1'     & 
            my.df[,1] != 'junk2' & my.df[,2] != 'junk2'     &
            my.df[,1] != '' & my.df[,2] != '') 
    , ]
```

Into:

```
# Rows I want
good.rows = (rowSums(is.na(my.df[,3:5]))  < (ncol(my.df)-2)) | 
           (rowSums(is.na(my.df[,3:5])) == (ncol(my.df)-2)  & 
            my.df[,1] != 'junk1' & my.df[,2] != 'junk1'     & 
            my.df[,1] != 'junk2' & my.df[,2] != 'junk2'     &
            my.df[,1] != '' & my.df[,2] != '') 

df.3 <- my.df[good.rows,]
```

And further:

```
sums.are.fine = (rowSums(is.na(my.df[,3:5]))  < (ncol(my.df)-2)) | 
           (rowSums(is.na(my.df[,3:5])) == (ncol(my.df)-2)

no.junk = my.df[,1] != 'junk1' & my.df[,2] != 'junk1'     & 
            my.df[,1] != 'junk2' & my.df[,2] != 'junk2'     &
            my.df[,1] != '' & my.df[,2] != '') 

good.rows = sums.are.fine & no.junk

df.3 <- my.df[good.rows,]
```

You could also write separate functions, such as `check.if.sums.are.fine(table.to.check)` which return a boolean, and a `check.everything(table.to.check)` function which calls all of these and gives the final result.

If the typing part bothers you, one thing I noticed is that for things like "Can't be `junk1` or `junk2` or null" you can make a `bad.values = character()` and populate this with every value you don't want, then simply check which values aren't contained in `bad.values` (this may take some work to add to your solution unless you use a for loop).